# SQL Database Creation - #1060 - Duplicate column name

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, erd

I was using [erdplus.com](https://erdplus.com/) to create an E/R diagram and generate relational tables from that, and then generate the SQL code to create a database from those tables. It looked like a solid tool. But when I generate the SQL code, I get the following error: #1060 - Duplicate column name.

I have probably done the E/R diagram incorrectly. Can anyone help me by pointing out my mistake? Beginner here.

[E/R Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njrme.png)

***This is the SQL Code to create the database that was auto-generated by erdplus. I have not yet populated the tables with any data- I was just at the first phase of testing whether it works or not: (See under for screenshot of error)***

CREATE TABLE Patient
(
Patient_Number INT NOT NULL,
Appointment_Number INT NOT NULL,
Patient_Name INT NOT NULL,
Patient_Address INT NOT NULL,
Amount_Owed INT NOT NULL,
Patient_Phone INT NOT NULL,
Specialist_Report INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Patient_Number),
UNIQUE (Appointment_Number)
);

CREATE TABLE Appointment
(
Appointment_Number INT NOT NULL,
Specialist_Referral_Number INT NOT NULL,
Patient_Number INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Appointment_Number),
FOREIGN KEY (Patient_Number) REFERENCES Patient(Patient_Number),
UNIQUE (Specialist_Referral_Number)
);

CREATE TABLE Treatment
(
Type_of_Treatment INT NOT NULL,
Appointment_Number INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Type_of_Treatment),
FOREIGN KEY (Appointment_Number) REFERENCES Appointment(Appointment_Number)
);

CREATE TABLE Treatment_Fees_Guidelines
(
Cost_of_Treatment INT NOT NULL,
Type_of_Treatment INT NOT NULL,
Type_of_Treatment INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Type_of_Treatment, Type_of_Treatment),
FOREIGN KEY (Type_of_Treatment) REFERENCES Treatment(Type_of_Treatment)
);

CREATE TABLE Bill
(
Cancellation_Fee INT NOT NULL,
Bill_Total INT NOT NULL,
Bill_Number INT NOT NULL,
Appointment_Number INT NOT NULL,
Appointment_Number INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Bill_Number),
FOREIGN KEY (Appointment_Number) REFERENCES Appointment(Appointment_Number),
UNIQUE (Appointment_Number)
);

CREATE TABLE Payment
(
Amount_Payed INT NOT NULL,
Payment_Type INT NOT NULL,
DropInOrPost INT NOT NULL,
BillNumber INT NOT NULL,
Bill_Number INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (BillNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (Bill_Number) REFERENCES Bill(Bill_Number)
);

CREATE TABLE Specialist
(
Name_of_Specialist INT NOT NULL,
Specialist_Referral_Number INT NOT NULL,
Appointment_Number INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Specialist_Referral_Number),
FOREIGN KEY (Appointment_Number) REFERENCES Appointment(Appointment_Number)
);

***The error is as follows and occurs at the 4th table (treatment_fees_guidelines).***

[Duplicate Column Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzRZX.png)

When I remove that column to experiment, I get the same error further down, the next time there is a duplicate column.

I guess my problem might be that I am unsure how to create the E/R diagram without it leading to duplicate columns. Would really appreciate anyones help here! Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you code:

```
CREATE TABLE Treatment_Fees_Guidelines ( Cost_of_Treatment INT NOT NULL, 
Type_of_Treatment INT NOT NULL, 
Type_of_Treatment INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (Type_of_Treatment, Type_of_Treatment), 
FOREIGN KEY (Type_of_Treatment) 
REFERENCES Treatment(Type_of_Treatment) );
```

is not correct because as you see, you have 2 columns with the same name: "Type_of_Treatment". Also, the duplication exists in the primary key definition. Primary key column(s) must have unique names of course.

Another thing (not a syntax error but probably a design error) is the FK for this table that is based on an logical design error in the Primary Key of the Treatment Table. The problem I see is that the Column "Type_of_Treatment" is not a good candidate as a primary key for this table. Maybe the name of the column is not good. May be I don't fully get your business rules!

Comment: Thanks NoChance, that really helped. I just didn't look closely enough at the actual code that was generated. I fixed all similar such errors throughout the SQL code and now its working just fine.

Comment: Nice to hear that. I suggest you don't fix the generated code. Instead make the changes to the model so that you can later use it to create valid code, of course this is assuming your model will evolve. If you think this answer is helpful please mark it as such so others know it is solved.